# Adding a widget collapses form

Tags: django

I have a script like this:

```py
#User model
about_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, validators=(MaxLengthValidator(1000),))

#forms.py
class SettingsUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('about_text')
        labels = {
            'about_text': '',
        }
```

This works and gives a nice big field to write a text.
[image: a big empty multiline text field]
Problem: If I add

```py
widgets = {
            'about_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe yourself!'}),
        }
```

the field collapses to a singleline field.
[image: A small, singleline text field that contains a placeholder text]
How do I keep the field big and have a placeholder?

Comment: i think you could achieve that by addin rows like: 'about_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe yourself!', 'rows':4,}),

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the error.
Apparently, a `CharField` translates to a `TextInput` and a `TextField` translates to a `TextArea`...
so changing `TextInput` to `TextArea` did the trick.